# SQLiteLog Accessing the log or piping it out [Android]

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Is there a way to access the SQLiteLog or at least pipe out errors to do with SQLite?

I would like to automatically send any errors, like the below, so I can optimise the database by adding in indexes, or making other changes as need be.

```
E/SQLiteLog: (284) automatic index on messages(chat_id)
```

It could well be that I'd only want to catch code 284, rather than getting everything. Is there a way of doing this when building the app, as would be useful to pass to crashlytics to help with development going forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A potential alternative, would be to run the queries preceded with `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`, and to then check for **`AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX`** in the results.

e.g.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (column1 TEXT, column2 TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (column3, column4);

EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN 
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE column1=column3;
```

Results in :-

[image]

As you can see this is based upon a predication of the number of rows rather than the actual number of rows, so works if there is no data (as above), which could well be beneficial, from a development perspective, as opposed to trying to trap on a as happens basis.

Comment: Seems like the best and easiest solution to implement - thanks!